# MoveIt tutorial: PR2 Gazebo Quick Start

Tags: ros, moveit, moveit-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the tutorial on [MoveIt wiki](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/index.php/Groovy/PR2/Gazebo/Quick_Start) it is promted to create the [pr2_moveit_controller_manager.launch](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/index.php/Groovy/PR2/Gazebo/Quick_Start#pr2_moveit_controller_manager.launch) file that includes a reference to `controller.yaml`. However the former is not included anywhere - neither in generated files nor in the files manualy added during tutorial.

How it is loaded then?

The "detailed documentation" refered from this section is empty yet. So I am a bit confused at this point.

Thanks,

Boris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54291/moveit-tutorial:-pr2-gazebo-quick-start/) by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3060 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a section on the [page link](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/index.php/Groovy/PR2/Gazebo/Quick_Start#pr2_moveit_controller_manager.launch) you posted titled "controllers.yaml" file, that describes how to create this file:

"This file should be created inside the config directory of the MoveIt! configuration package generated for your robot by the Setup Assistant. This file does not exist yet - it has not been auto-generated by the MoveIt! Setup Assistant. "

It says to copy-paste their version into your config directory. Did you try this yet?

EDIT (per comment)
Got it. What you need to do is create the pr2_moveit_controller_manager.launch file in the launch folder of your configuration package. Within that file you will see the line

> rosparam file="$(find pr2_moveit_generated)/config/controllers.yaml"

That is where it is referenced.

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-02-19**:
Sorry for confusion. The question is not how to create this file, but how it is called by the system. I was unable to find anything that uses this file. So, the next question would be - why should I even bother to create it? It is also not mentioned anywhere in future tutorials.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-02-19**:
Ah, I see. So it is then used through the parameter server. I somehow was inattentive and was thinking it is  and **not** , which is a big difference. Thanks to point this out!